# Javascript remove the first line of a string just before the line break

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that contains a string with lots of line breaks.

```
myvariable = '
1234556788,3434343434\n
1244556788,7234343834\n
1234556788,4434343434\n
1234556784,8434343434\n
1234556782,9444343434\n
';
```

I need some way of removing just the first one without leaving a blank first line if possible.

So that this:

```
1234556788,3434343434\n
1244556788,7234343834\n
1234556788,4434343434\n
1234556784,8434343434\n
1234556782,9444343434\n
```

turns into this:

```
1244556788,7234343834\n
1234556788,4434343434\n
1234556784,8434343434\n
1234556782,9444343434\n
```

So it would remove the first line after the \n

How can I do this?

Comment: one simple way is to convert to an array by splitting at newlines, remove the first element, then join again by newline character

Comment: Show what have you tried to solve this problem.

Comment: You have a LEADING newline AND TWO newlines per line if your code looks like you posted - is that intended?

Comment: Perhaps you mean `myvariable = myvariable.split(/\s+/).slice(2).join("\n")`  https://jsfiddle.net/zmayf1hx/

Answer (score -1):

```js
myvariable = `1234556788,3434343434\n
1244556788,7234343834\n
1234556788,4434343434\n
1234556784,8434343434\n
1234556782,9444343434\n
`;
myvariable.substring(myvariable.indexOf('\n') + 2, myvariable.length);
```

Comment: Note that template literals also preserve newlines, so `myvariable` now has two newlines every time.